Facing the error "fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly" while pushing using Git
I've been working on a big project for months, and I used to do some git push and git pull all the time without any problem... But, right now, I'm facing these errors while trying to push my commits to my GitLab repo:
client_loop: send disconnect: Connection reset by peer
fatal: sha1 file '<stdout>' write error: Broken pipe
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly

Also, the pushing process gets stuck while writing objects, meaning that whenever I want to push, it'll get stuck at a specific percent, and then drop the above errors...
I tried these:

Using these Git proxies (I live in Iran, but I haven't ever been using any type of proxies, at least from one year ago till this day!)

setting postBuffer to 524288000 (despite the fact that the project doesn't have any large files at all...)

Using these commands:
git config --global http.postBuffer 1048576000
git config --global http.lowSpeedLimit 0
git config --global http.lowSpeedTime 999999



But, none of them works... Any idea?
